# jQuery Appending script tags

Tags: jquery

I have the following which adds script tags to my page (which comes from json)

```
$(".a-games").html(data.aff_code);
```

which looks something like this

```
"aff_code":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"https:\/\/www.gambling-affiliation.com\/oddsbb\/iv=fnBZihb3qIYYZlAdGp-o7rJHq-d.nc-.InZjJO4Tu44ZQYScZDs2dIYHUabyBik2ThzohOgZeWccJmFtZXrVW7IflTmLSpWFfDzH-YMYC0f5frS0T02eRhpalfgltAGEbqaX.Z2emTll.jGlnWhfR-Rc6stC7CaH5K4Ck6ajzwuimsh9tAzfKdna1kdkpvqaF6BA9nia0KODitIlqHCddiuubSbBPjgLew9NeRkfSqk0sbLoYw1gmzx87apRXSdVaTK7oTfUTJzj5clBBP1VXanOTzqK4DxIu7Q24KTbH1nCcc2on5eEAMOYRxe88I30b5t1QQTYfL8EU1HUVIJNEOPfzMiTbKIupfPdkMZzzMRaop.4eFmyhbMgjylfMXfaHIlAu-d2wWvhorfyMiE-lKtVgkBK6oqCEX12Y7MsOGSKHF8e00ay.muDeyLyjv4xkrmVR-1XLYuMeAer7ERHWk.ZIFRke9CMvit25twcZd9IVZkQd45IxapQSoK33mEzVNdOpGq.i0DIadjKSF9IWu8LLxU9Y1.9hjLIurUfnortqO0O.b-EUp1xBfUdEmCrqMZFO11US-r1j6IyP7-sNEdoEwOYK.EFaoMKS9EzXVxY1BiZ40iiQizg9xZxpOaPv7pS.lQ4qT3f2EjZ1OT8mLE8TFg6zICpEVULmQps8HMBhh108-kltAKVdjD-t5tZWixxUryrB8orHhyzAJeQlFHCUtWsgOSMPgcdhzm3STt4UcS27prBqgJGIqIq4igZrttOMSXmLjfnlV3C1IFfUplfOrNP7u8osL4XMxzYL6c_GA1337\"><\/script>"
```

It loads it to my page, I can see when I inspect the element, but it doesn't show when viewing the page - what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a script from a URL and load it using `jQuery` you can use `$.getScript()`.
The script is retrieved via a `GET HTTP request`. It provides a function as a callback, so you can be sure the script is loaded and read status code of your request.
As provided in the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) it is equivalent to :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```